# How to remove trailing whitespace in code, using another script?

Tags: python

Something like:

```
import fileinput

for lines in fileinput.FileInput("test.txt", inplace=1):
    lines = lines.strip()
    if lines == '': continue
    print lines
```

But nothing is being printed on stdout.

Assuming some string named `foo`:

```
foo.lstrip() # to remove leading white space
foo.rstrip() # to remove trailing whitespace
foo.strip()  # to remove both lead and trailing whitespace
```

Comment: You sure that's not related to the use of `fileinput.FileInput` instead?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`fileinput` seems to be for multiple input streams. This is what I would do:

```
with open("test.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: i am getting error:  ./fix2.py 
  File "./fix2.py", line 2
    with file as open("xmlrunner.py"):
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: It's the other way around, with open(bla) as file: ... also, I would remove the continue: if line: print line

Comment: @kamal: Hah, I got the `with` statement backwards. Fixed now.

Comment: @Sebastian: Yeah, that is better. Also fixed.

Answer (score 12):

You don't see any output from the `print` statements because `FileInput` redirects `stdout` to the input file when the keyword argument `inplace=1` is given. This causes the input file to effectively be rewritten and if you look at it afterwards the lines in it will indeed have no trailing or leading whitespace in them (except for the newline at the end of each which the `print` statement adds back).

If you only want to remove trailing whitespace, you should use `rstrip()` instead of `strip()`. Also note that the `if lines == '': continue` is causing blank lines to be completely removed (regardless of whether `strip` or `rstrip` gets used).

Unless your intent is to rewrite the input file, you should probably just use `for line in open(filename):`. Otherwise you can see what's being written to the file by simultaneously echoing the output to `sys.stderr` using something like the following (which will work in both Python 2 and 3):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
import sys

for line in (line.rstrip() for line in
                fileinput.FileInput("test.txt", inplace=1)):
    if line:
        print(line)
        print(line, file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to tidy up for PEP8, this will trim trailing whitespace for your whole project:

```
import os

PATH = '/path/to/your/project'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
    for f in files:
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
        if file_extension == '.py':
            path_name = os.path.join(path, f)
            with open(path_name, 'r') as fh:
                new = [line.rstrip() for line in fh]
            with open(path_name, 'w') as fh:
                [fh.write('%s\n' % line) for line in new]
```

Comment: Necro-comment: At the very end, instead of wasting resources creating a throw-away list, it would be more efficient to use a single file output call with an argument that was generator expression: i.e. `fh.writelines((line+'\n' for line in new))`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing that `sed` is *really* good at: `$ sed 's/[ \t]*$//'`. Be aware the you will probably need to literally type a TAB character instead of `\t` for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, fileinput.FileInput is a generator. As such, you can only iterate over it once, then all items have been consumed and calling it's ***next*** method raises **StopIteration**. If you want to iterate over the lines more than once, you can put them in a list:

```
list(fileinput.FileInput('test.txt'))
```

Then call **rstrip** on them.

Answer (score 3):

Save as `fix_whitespace.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Fix trailing whitespace and line endings (to Unix) in a file.
Usage: python fix_whitespace.py foo.py
"""

import os
import sys


def main():
    """ Parse arguments, then fix whitespace in the given file """
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        fname = sys.argv[1]
        if not os.path.exists(fname):
            print("Python file not found: %s" % sys.argv[1])
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("Invalid arguments. Usage: python fix_whitespace.py foo.py")
        sys.exit(1)
    fix_whitespace(fname)


def fix_whitespace(fname):
    """ Fix whitespace in a file """
    with open(fname, "rb") as fo:
        original_contents = fo.read()
    # "rU" Universal line endings to Unix
    with open(fname, "rU") as fo:
        contents = fo.read()
    lines = contents.split("\n")
    fixed = 0
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        new_line = line.rstrip()
        if len(line) != len(new_line):
            lines[k] = new_line
            fixed += 1
    with open(fname, "wb") as fo:
        fo.write("\n".join(lines))
    if fixed or contents != original_contents:
        print("************* %s" % os.path.basename(fname))
    if fixed:
        slines = "lines" if fixed > 1 else "line"
        print("Fixed trailing whitespace on %d %s" \
              % (fixed, slines))
    if contents != original_contents:
        print("Fixed line endings to Unix (\\n)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This thing can wipe out a file entirely if it crashes and it did for me.  Thankfully git saved the day, of course.
```
$ fix_whitespace.py foo.py 
/home/user/bin/fix_whitespace.py:29: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
  with open(fname, "rU") as fo:
  ...
  File "/home/user/bin/fix_whitespace.py", line 39, in fix_whitespace
    fo.write("\n".join(lines))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit surprising seeing multiple answers suggesting to use `python` for this task, as there's no need to write a multi-line program for this.

Standard Unix tools like `sed`, `awk` or `perl` can achieve this easily straight from the command-line.

e.g anywhere you have `perl` (Windows, Mac, Linux) the following should achieve what the OP asked:

```
perl -i -pe 's/[ \t]+$//;' files...
```

Explanation of the arguments to `perl`:

```
-i   # run the edit "in place" (modify the original file)
-p   # implies a loop with a final print over every input line
-e   # next arg is the perl expression to apply (to every line)
```

`s/[ \t]$//`  is a substitution regex s/FROM/TO/: replace every trailing (end of line) non-empty space (spaces or tabs) with nothing.

Advantages:

- One liner, no programming needed
- Works on multiple (any number) of files
- Works correctly on standard-input (no file arguments given)

> **Edit:**
>
> Newer versions of `perl` support `\h` (any horizontal-space character), so the solution becomes even shorter:
>
> `perl -i -pe 's/\h+$//;' files...`

More generally, if you want to modify any number of files directly from the command line, replacing every appearance of `FOO` with `BAR`, you may always use this generic template:

```
perl -i -pe 's/FOO/BAR/' files...
```