# Removing whitespaces in a text file in python

Tags: python, strip

```
file1 = open("store.txt", "r")
for line in file1:
    print(line.rstrip())
file1.close()
```

This is the text file :

```
   Electronics:iPhone,3999;Galaxy,2999;Xiaomi,1999;
   Home Products:      Oven,   2950;      Microwave,   1950;      Chair,   350;
   Wood Products: Chair, 350; Table, 9999; Bed, 12250;
```

I expected the method would remove the whitspaces from every line, what am i missing here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove trailing whitespace in code, using another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411603/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-code-using-another-script)

Comment: Do you want to remove _all whitespace_, or only whitespace on the right side (i.e. trailing on each line) which is what `rstrip` does?

Comment: Yes you’re removing the spaces from the lines read from the file, but you’re not modifying the file - you’ll have to write the modified lines to a new file.

Comment: With a quick look at the code, it doesn't change the file itself; it simply prints stuff out. to the screen. Also, you should use `with open` instead of open.

Comment: If you want your `print` statements to replace the file contents, you can use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module.

Comment: I will add that `rstrip()` stands for "RightStrip". you should use regular `strip()` if you want to remove the white spaces from both sides

Comment: And if you also want to remove the spaces in the middle, `line.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: @MatsLindh Initially yes i wanted to modify the file and to remove all whitespaces, but i did not succeed so i went on to print the lines without the spaces to see where i was failing.

Comment: Even the briefest look at the documentation for `rstrip()` would have revealed it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I am bit late, thought to share this with you if in case useful.

```
for line in open('store.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines():
    line = ' '.join(line.split())
    print(line)
```

This is the output:

```
Electronics:iPhone,3999;Galaxy,2999;Xiaomi,1999;
Home Products: Oven, 2950; Microwave, 1950; Chair, 350;
Wood Products: Chair, 350; Table, 9999; Bed, 12250;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file1 = open("store.txt", "r")
for line in file1:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.replace(" ", "")
    if line:
        print(line)
file1.close()
```

Thank you all in the comments, This works for me.